# Google Apps Script to remove hangouts links from calendar events

Tags: google-apps-script

I have successfully accessed a Google calendar event and can change the color, but I'm stuck when it comes to removing the hangouts link.

I'm attempting to use code to automatically remove the hangouts links when I am the meeting originator and have not changed the hangout name, but I'm not having any success in actually changing the link.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
function removehangout() {
   var calendarId = 'primary';
   //var calendars = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName('Mirage ELDRIDGE');
   var now = new Date();
  // Determines how many events are happening in the next 24 hours x 1 days.
  var now = new Date();
  var endr = new Date(now.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var events2 = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, endr);
  Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events2.length); 
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 5
  });
  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
        var event1 = events.items[i];
        var d = event1.description;
        var ttitle = event1.summary;
        var whoby = event1.creator.email;
        Logger.log(ttitle + ' by: ' + whoby);
        if(whoby.indexOf('mirage.eldridge') != -1){
          Logger.log(ttitle + '--> was by mirage');
          var hangoutname = event1.hangoutLink;
          Logger.log(ttitle + '--> hangout link name --> ' + hangoutname);
          if (hangoutname != null) {
            if (hangoutname.indexOf('mirage-eldridge') != -1){
              //delete this link here
              Logger.log(ttitle + '--> remove hangout');
              //event.setHangoutLink(null);
             //var idno = event.iCalUID
              //CalendarApp.getEventSeriesById(idno)
              event1.HangoutLink = null;
              Logger.log(ttitle + '... ' + event1.hangoutLink);
              Logger.log(event1.iCalUID);
              //event.setcolorId('11');


              var event2 = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, event1.id)
              event2.colorId = 9;
              event2.hangoutLink = 'fred';
              //Calendar.Events.patch(event2,calendarId,event1.id);
              Calendar.Events.update(event2,calendarId,event1.id);
            }
          } else {
            Logger.log(ttitle + ' -- do not remove ' + hangoutname);

          }
        }
        if (!d)
            d = '';
        //var foundlinkyes = d.indexOf('HangoutLink');
        //var actuallink = event.hangoutLink;
        //var hasrlink = 'True';
      //if (!actuallink) {
        //Logger.log(ttitle + ' no link found');
        //hasrlink = "False";
      //}
      //Logger.log('desc: ' + ttitle + '--  foundyes: ' + foundlinkyes);
        //if (foundlinkyes == -1 && hasrlink == 'True'){

           //if (event.hangoutLink && (d.indexOf('Hangout: ')== -1)){
               //Logger.log (event.summary + ' - ' + event.hangoutLink + ' - ' + event.description);
               //Logger.log(ttitle + ' added this ' + event.hangoutLink);
               //event.description = 'HangoutLink: ' + event.hangoutLink + '\n\n' + d;
               //Calendar.Events.update(event, calendarId, event.id);
               //foundlinkyes = 0;
               //hasrlink = 'True';
           //}
         //}

    }
} else {
    Logger.log('No events found.');
}
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  Running into the same issue.

Comment: No luck so far in removing the automatically generated hangouts/meet link in calendar invites.

I have seen a different behaviour lately where meetings with no invitees do not get the automatic hangout/meet link, however, deleting the auto generated links where there will be no hangout/meet (aka a face-to-face) is still problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `null` the `conferenceData`. Here it is how to do it:

```js
function deleteMeetLink() {
  const calendarId = ID_CALENDAR;
  const eventId = ID_EVENT;
  const event = CalendarApi.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
  const request = {
    ...event,
    conferenceData: null,
  };
  CalendarApi.Events.update(request, calendarId, eventId, {conferenceDataVersion: 1});
}
```